# Which is the supporting dll for ActiveXObject("FILECTL.FileSystem") in WinCE 5.0 and how to use it?

Tags: javascript, activex, windows-ce

I want to read an .ini file which is there in device file system in WinCE 5.0 through ASP.
For which i have used ActiveXObject("FILECTL.FileSystem").
But, getting the error as 
Parse error in script Microsoft JScript runtime error: '800a01ad'
Description: Automation server can't create object 
Which dll should be used for this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `FILECTL.FileSystem` object was a COM object inside the old eMbedded Visual Basic runtimes that were deprecated back in about 2003.  I just checked the Platform Builder 6.0 tree and no file with the name "FILECTL" exists and no registry entry (for registering the COM component) exists.  I'm going to conclude from this that, at least as of 6.0, it doesn't exist.  It likely doesn't exist in 5.0 either, since the eVB runtimes were dropped long before CE 5.0 was released.

Generally speaking, if you need access to device resources from a web page, you'll need to author your own COM component (that implements `IObjectSafety` for the browser to access it) and include it in your OS image.